# Am I allowed to move around an operator like this?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, differential-operators

Can I take this product:

$$\frac{dL}{dt}\frac{d L}{d \dot{x}}$$

And factor out one of the $L$'s to get:

$$L\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{d L}{d \dot{x}}\right)$$

Where the operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ now operates on $\frac{d L}{d \dot{x}}$?

Is this allowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only allowed if $L$ is not a function of $t$. If $L$ is a function of $t$, then this is not allowed.

This is not factoring though, but using the identity that
$$\frac{d}{d\,x}(cf(x))=c\frac{d}{d\,x}f(x).$$

Comment: Thanks.  $L$ is a typical Lagrangian $L=L(x,\dot{x},t)$, so it is a function of $x$ which is in turn parameterized by $t$.  I guess this means that the identity does not apply.

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Comment: I think you're making a mistake in interpreting $\big(\!\frac{dL}{dt}\!\big)\big(\!\frac{dL}{d\dot x}\!\big)$ as $\frac d{dt}\!\big(L\frac{dL}{d\dot x}\!\big)$.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking whether they are equal?  Have you tried an example?  Almost any one where the first expression is nonzero will do.